# Silence Deface log output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree, deface

I am getting a crap-ton of log noise from Deface. I'm not the view guy on my current project and I'd really like to remove that crap from the logs. I'd also imagine that on a live production application you'd want to silence or suppress that as well. I have a hook that silences asset output already...is my best bet to just put this in there as additional logic or is there some configuration for Deface and/or Spree to silence the log noise?

Comment: Please show examples of this logging output.

Comment: @RyanBigg I came here searching for a solution for this. Getting all the info-level Deface output in production logs, eg `Deface: 2 overrides found for 'spree/orders/_line_item'`

Comment: That'd be because the default log level within Rails is "info", and those are info messages. In `development`, it's "debug" instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks @RyanBigg. so set

```
config.log_level = :warn
```

in /config/environments/production.rb or /config/environments/development.rb as needed.

There doesn't seem to way to specifically silence Deface with a setting, but if Deface were to have its own logger that wraps its calls to Rails.logger, that might be a good feature.

Comment: This is an excellent idea. The only limitation is that I end up not seeing my other more valid 'debug' and 'warn' level output but that's small. I can simply use $stderr.puts for those things on this project. Thanks!